# Rotating Axes with a SQL table

Tags: postgresql

I have a table:

```
product   asset    count
 foo        x        1
 bar        x        0
 foo        y        2
 bar        y        1
```

this is an abbreviated version.  There are around 80 assets, and a few hundred products.

Is it possible with SQL to turn this table into something like this?

```
product   asset x   asset y
foo          1         2
bar          0         1
```

bearing in mind that this data has come from three tables, `products`, `assets` and `assets_products`

Comment: Is it possible? Most certainly. [What have you tried?](http://whathaveyoutried.com)

Answer (score 1):

What you want to do is `crosstab`.

To do that, you can use the [`tablefunc` contrib](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/tablefunc.html), and the following query:

```
SELECT * FROM crosstab(
    'SELECT product, asset, count FROM <your_table> ORDER BY 1, 2')
    AS (product text, asset_x int, asset_y int);
```

Comment: The problem here is that I want the asset types columns to be driven by the data.

Comment: @NeilMiddleton, so the only solutions seems to dynamically generate the query or even show the result dynamically on your application (seems better), because PostgreSQL always need information about the columns returned by a query.